# Headphone output is far too loud

Tags: sound, soundcard, headphones, volume-control

**I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot), with a "Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)" sound card.**

When I plug headphones into the front headphone port, the sound that comes out is far too loud to listen to - and has to be turned down to about 5%. Anything above that is distorted and deafening.

I have played around in Alsamixer, and whilst a decent level can be achieved (through changing three separate sliders), this is not ideal for changing the volume on my parents' computer. And using the standard volume control overrides all of that anyway.

Answer (score 13):

I experienced the same problem and I have written a post about the solution I found [here](http://dragly.org/2011/10/13/fixing-the-volume-treshold-and-intervals-in-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-m1330/). Basically what I did was this:

Open the file **/etc/pulse/default.pa** by typing the following in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Change the line that says

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

into

```
load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1
```

Save and close the file.

Restart pulseaudio by typing the following in a terminal:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Now open alsamixer:

```
alsamixer
```

Then lower the PCM volume to a decent level (I set mine to about 50 %). After doing this, changing the volume using the volume keys or volume slider won't reset the settings for PCM in alsamixer and will let you keep the lowest threshold of the volume a as low as you'd like. This will also keep the volume intervals smaller. The only negative effect is that you won't get as much sound out of your speakers without headphones unless you change back the PCM settings in alsamixer again.

I can't guarantee that this will work on your system, but it did work nicely on mine.

Comment: This made the volume keys/slider stop working on my system, but at least my earbuds are no longer at 11!

Comment: Many thanks! Worked really well on my Arch Linux. No need to use VolumeLock on Windows anymore.

Comment: This worked very well for me in Ubuntu 22.04.2. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

None of the solutions worked for me.

Here's what got my issue solved:

Edit `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common`

```
sudo vim /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
```

Change:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all 
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

To:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
volume-limit = 0.01
override-map.1 = all 
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

Adjust `volume-limit` so that it fits your headphones volume range. In my case `0.01` was good.

Restart pulseaudio: `pulseaudio -k` or reboot `sudo reboot`

Full credits to this site. https://chrisjean.com/fix-for-usb-audio-is-too-loud-and-mutes-at-low-volume-in-ubuntu/

**UPDATE:**

The above solution overwrites all sound outputs. Hence, lowering your speakers volume limit too.

In order to lower only headphones max, set the above config into the `[Option Analog Output:Headphones]` section (same `analog-output.conf.common`).

Before:

```
[Option Analog Output:Headphones]
name = output-headphones
priority = 9
```

After:

```
[Option Analog Output:Headphones]
name = output-headphones
priority = 9
volume = ignore
volume-limit = 0.0
```

Comment: Applying this to 
[Option Analog Output:Speakers] fixed a similar issue with the built-in speakers of an Asus laptop running Linux Mint (Cinnamon) 18.3, thanks! 0.01 seems to be a good value.

Comment: I was reading up some docs and volume limit of 1.00 appears to the job as well. If I change it to .05 or .5 or any other value it doesn't seem to have any marginal effect.

Comment: In order to get the right sound output reference, check the Ubuntu sound settings. In my case, the headset is identified by "Speakers - USB Audio Device". Thus, I added volume-limit = 1 (that was personally a good value) to "Option Analog Output:Speakers".

Comment: I applied this solution and the sound quality is better on my headphones, but now I have no sound from the laptop's internal speakers :(

Answer (score 4):

None of the above works for me even after searching solution for hours.

For me, I just had to change my sound card, and there, I find it exactly what I want.

The steps which I followed were:

1. Type `alsamixer` in terminal and hit enter
2. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> and choose your sound card (I selected *USB PnP Sound Device* as I was using USB headphones) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Here you'll find the volume bars, adjust the one for your USB headphone so it is not too loud.

Comment: This is exactly what helped me. The other solutions seem hackish to me, but not this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**I solved this using sound settings in system settings**. On the bottom of the screen, to the left of the "Test Speakers" button is a drop-down labeled "Profile:". I changed it to "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" from "Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)". And now I can turn the volume down more.

Editing `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common`
and `/etc/pulse/default.pa` did not work for me, as some other answers suggested. My problem remained after changing these configs.

The original problem I was experiencing: the sound in my bluetooth headphones would sound bearably quiet but then within a second of playing a video it would gradually increase. This was at the lowest system volume setting - one more keyboard button press to lower the volume would mute the headphones.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I changed my USB Headset Profile to "Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958)" and the range is now perfect.

Answer (score 1):

With most soundcards there are different mixer channels which amplify themselves. You can try to turn down the headphone output so that you can regulate the volume with the master mixer more accurate. It may be, that you have to install the pavucontrol package by typing `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`. At least I hope that the gnome3-developers kept this options in their sound-setting tools ;)